# Crystal Reports VB.NET--use sql select command and add a datacolumn

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I am using VB .NET and the Visual Studio Crystal Reports Tool.  I am generating a report that uses an SQL query, fills the datatable, and adds a datacolumn based on the field values in the datatable.  The datatable is populated, but doesn't display on the report.  I am using an XSD file as the datasource for the report which contains the SQL query fields as well as the datacolumn field.

```
Dim sqlAdapter As New SqlDataAdapter()
Dim dt As New DataTable
sqlAdapter.SelectCommand = New SqlCommand(SELECT * FROM [database], validConnectionString)
sqlAdapter.Fill(dt)

Dim addedColumn As New DataColumn ("addedColumn", Type.GetType("System.String"))
dt.Columns.Add(addedColumn)

'Logic to fill the column (tested and used without fail throughout other parts of project)

Dim bsv As New CRReportViewer 'class type that works for all other reports
Dim rpt As New CompletedReport 'class type that follow pattern that works elsewhere
bsv.DataContext = Me
rpt.SetDataSource(dt)
bsv.ReportViewer.ViewerCore.ReportSource = rpt
bsv.Show()
```

If I insert something like 'MsgBox(dt.Rows(0).Item("addedColumn)) I get a valid value.  This value doesn't appear in the report however.  Everything within the SelectCommand appears without problem.

Comment: r u want to genrate dynamic fields for Report

Comment: It is a dynamic field.  However I was required to do it on the sql side.  The issue was setting a cangrow property.  The field was at max one character and when the field was longer the field defaulted to null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above code does work.  The problem was a setting within the field of the .rpt file.  There was a problem with its length and default submission.

As an aside, it seems that once dt contains valid entries--everything else falls in the Crystal reports editor and the .rpt file.